# is it possible to use MysqlCommandBuilder with big enough data?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mysql-connector

i have 1 table in database with 10 columns and less than 1000 data in it.

instead of using text box to insert, update, delete. I want it to be done directly in the datagridview. is it possible to use CommandBuilder ? or is there a good one?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a complete non sequitur. How much data there is is irrelevant to whether or not you can or should use a comm and builder. I have a feeling that there may be a limit on the number of columns, although that would be provider-specific if it's true, but the number of rows is irrelevant. The main issues to consider regarding a command builder are whether the query involves a single table and whether it retrieves key information. If both are true then you can use a command builder. I still suggest that you don't use one though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry, let's say I have 10 columns with a lot of data less than 1000..
and it only involves 1 table

Comment: Mysql .net connector has a command builder class... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommandBuilder.htm

Comment: Use a data adapter to `Fill` a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to your control(s). That could be a `DataGridView` or discrete controls; it doesn't matter. Once you've made all the changes you want to make to the data, use the same data adapter to `Update` the database. You can use a command builder or create the action commands yourself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Your suggestions are very helpful..thank you.